# Memory leaks in lottery simulator

Tags: python, memory-management, simulation

I'm primarily a C++/Java programmer, but I've recently started using Python at work and decided to write a Lottery Simulator at home.  I wrote it to test out different combinations of lottery numbers against a set of winning numbers to calculate how much I would have won (I also run the lotto pool at work).  The only major problem I've seen with the code is that it has a substantial memory leak that I just can't seem to track down.  I've already plugged one large leak.

I'd really appreciate any help you can provide in tracking down the leak(s).  The code is pretty large (655 lines), but a lot of it is comments & blank lines for readability.  Also feel free to use the code yourself if you want, I'm not copyrighting it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random, ConfigParser, ast, copy
from optparse import OptionParser

# Global variables.
g_config = {}         # Stores GameType config options.
g_prizes = {}         # Stores prizes from config file.
g_prize_amounts = {}    # Stores prize amounts from config file.
g_ticket_quick_picks = []   # Store an array of QuickPicks to use for tickets.
g_total_money_won = 0
g_total_tickets_won = 0
g_prizes_won = {}       # Format: {'3':3, '3+1':2, '4':2 ...}
g_quick_pick_file = ''
g_how_many_tickets_played = 0
g_how_many_tickets_won = 0


class TicketNumbers( object ):
  '''Represents the numbers of a ticket (or the 7 winning numbers).
  @var numbers: A sorted array of 7 unique numbers from 1-49.'''

  def __init__( self, numbers ):
    '''Constructor.
    @param numbers: The numbers for this ticket.'''

    self.numbers = numbers
    self._set_numbers( numbers )

  def name( self ):
    '''Return the name of this class type.'''
    return "TicketNumbers"

  def __str__( self ):
    '''Returns a string of the number list.'''
    str_nums = []
    for i in range( len( self.numbers ) ):
      str_nums.append( str( self.numbers[i] ) )

    return ', '.join( str_nums )

  def _set_numbers( self, numbers ):
    '''Sets the numbers member variable and validates the numbers.
    @param numbers: The numbers to assign.'''

    global g_config
    self.numbers = sorted( numbers )

    if len( self.numbers ) != int(g_config['how_many_numbers']):
      raise Exception( "You must have %d numbers, but found %d numbers: %s" % (g_config['how_many_numbers'], len( self.numbers ), str(self.numbers)) )
    tmp = []

    for num in self.numbers:
      # Check if numbers are in range.
      if ( num < int(g_config['min_number']) ) or ( num > int(g_config['max_number']) ):
        raise Exception( "The numbers must be between %d & %d!" % (int(g_config['min_number']), int(g_config['max_number'])) )
      # Check for duplicate numbers.
      if num in tmp:
        raise Exception( "You cannot have duplicate numbers!  %d in %s" % (num, str( self.numbers )) )
      tmp.append( num )


class PlayedTicket( TicketNumbers ):
  '''Represents a ticket that was played.
  @var amount_won: How much $$ this ticket won.'''

  def __init__( self, numbers ):
    '''Constructor.
    @param numbers: The numbers for this ticket.'''

    super( PlayedTicket, self ).__init__( numbers )
    self.amount_won = {}  # Map of Game Index to $$ won each play.
    self.tickets_won = {}   # Map of Game Index to Free Tickets won each play.

 def name( self ):
    '''Return the name of this class type.'''
    return "PlayedTicket"

  def compare_with( self, winning_numbers, game_index=None ):
    '''Compares this ticket with the specified winning numbers and sets the amount_won & tickets_won members accordingly.
    @param winning_numbers: The winning numbers to compare against.
    @param game_index: (optional) The game index for this game.  Defaults to 1 + the number of games recorded.
    @return: A tuple of ($$ won, # free tickets won).'''

    global g_config, g_prizes, g_prize_amounts, g_prizes_won, g_how_many_tickets_won
    nums_correct = 0
    bonus_correct = 0
    amount_won = 0
    tickets_won = 0

    if game_index == None:
      game_index = len( self.amount_won )

    # Check each individual number of the ticket against the winning numbers.
    for num in self.numbers:
      if num in winning_numbers.numbers:
        nums_correct = nums_correct + 1
      elif num in winning_numbers.bonus_numbers:
        bonus_correct = bonus_correct + 1

    # Now see if we won anything.
    for (key, value) in g_prizes.items():
      main_nums = key[0]
      bonus_nums = key[1]

      if (main_nums == nums_correct) and ((bonus_nums == bonus_correct) or (bonus_nums == 0)):
        if not g_prizes_won.has_key( value ):
          g_prizes_won[value] = 0

        g_how_many_tickets_won = g_how_many_tickets_won + 1
        g_prizes_won[value] = g_prizes_won[value] + 1  # Increment map of how many times each prize won. 

        # We won.   Now figure out what we won.
        if g_prize_amounts[value] > amount_won:
          amount_won = g_prize_amounts[value]
          tickets_won = 0
        elif g_prize_amounts[value] == -1:
          amount_won = 0
          tickets_won = 1

    if amount_won or tickets_won:
      if g_config['verbose']:
        print( "Ticket %s won: $%d & %d Free tickets." % (str(self.numbers), amount_won, tickets_won) )

    # Set and return the amount won.
    self.amount_won[game_index] = amount_won
    self.tickets_won[game_index] = tickets_won
    return (amount_won, tickets_won)


class QuickPick( PlayedTicket ):
  '''Represents a Quick Pick ticket.'''

  def __init__( self, numbers ):
    '''Constructor.
    @param numbers: The numbers for this ticket.'''

    super( QuickPick, self ).__init__( numbers )
    self.amount_won = {}  # Map of Game Index to $$ won each play.
    self.tickets_won = {}   # Map of Game Index to Free Tickets won each play.

  def name( self ):
    '''Return the name of this class type.'''
    return "QuickPick"


class WinningNumbers( TicketNumbers ):
  '''Represents the winning numbers + bonus number.
  @var bonus_numbers: The bonus numbers.'''

  def __init__( self, numbers, bonus_numbers=None ):
    '''Constructor.
    @param numbers: The winning numbers.
    @param bonus_numbers: (optional) The bonus number(s).  Defaults to empty list.'''

    global g_config
    bonus_numbers = bonus_numbers or []
    super( WinningNumbers, self ).__init__( numbers )
    self.bonus_numbers = []
    if bonus_numbers:
      self.bonus_numbers = sorted( bonus_numbers )
    tmp = []

    if len( bonus_numbers ) != int(g_config['how_many_bonus']):
      raise Exception( "You must have %d bonus numbers!" % int(g_config['how_many_bonus']) )

    for num in bonus_numbers:
      if (num in tmp) or (num in self.numbers):
        raise Exception( "You cannot have duplicate numbers!" )
      tmp.append( num )

  def __str__( self ):
    '''Converts this class into a string.'''
    ret = super( WinningNumbers, self ).__str__()

    str_bnums = []

    if len( self.bonus_numbers ):
      for i in range( len( self.bonus_numbers ) ):
        str_bnums.append( str( self.bonus_numbers[i] ) )

      ret = ret + ' + ' + ', '.join( str_bnums )

    return ret


  def name( self ):
    '''Return the name of this class type.'''
    return "WinningNumbers"


def load_config( filename ):
  '''Reads the config file to load program defaults.
  @param filename: The filename of the config file.
  @return: A ConfigParser object containing the parsed config file.'''

  # Read the config file into the parser.
  global g_config, g_prizes, g_prize_amounts
  conf = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
  conf.read( filename )

  if (not conf.has_section( 'GameType' )) or (not conf.has_section( 'Prizes' )):
    raise Exception( "Invalid config file!  [GameType] and/or [Prizes] sections are missing!" )

  options = ['min_number', 'max_number', 'how_many_numbers', 'how_many_bonus', 'how_many_hand_picked_lines', 'how_many_quick_pick_lines', 'cost_per_ticket', 'quick_pick_pool_size', 'how_many_tickets_bought']

  for option in options:
    if not conf.has_option( 'GameType', option ):
      raise Exception( "Invalid config file!  '%s' option is missing!" % option )

    g_config[option] = int( conf.get( 'GameType', option ) )

  # Prizes section contains maps.
  g_prizes = ast.literal_eval( conf.get( 'Prizes', 'prizes' ) )
  g_prize_amounts = ast.literal_eval( conf.get( 'Prizes', 'prize_amounts' ) )


def load_tickets_conf( filename ):
  '''Loads tickets from a config file.
  @param filename: The filename to load the tickets from.
  @return: A map of # of tickets to an array of Tickets.'''

  # Read the config file into the parser.
  conf.read( filename )
  ticket_map = {}

  # First read the 'all_groups' option that contains a list of all ticket groups.
  if not conf.has_section( 'AllTicketGroups' ):
    raise Exception( "Invalid config file!  [AllTicketGroups] section is missing!" )

  all_groups = parse_number_line( conf.get( 'AllTicketGroups', 'all_groups' ) )

  # Then read each ticket group and add the tickets to the map.
  for group in all_groups:
    if not conf.has_section( str( group ) ):
      raise Exception( "Invalid config file!  [%d] section is missing!" % group )

    tickets = []

    for i in range( 1, group + 1 ):
      if not conf.has_option( str( group ), str( i ) ):
        raise Exception( "Invalid config file!  There is no '%d' option under the [%d] section!" % (i, group) )

      numbers = parse_number_line( conf.get( str( group ), str( i ) ) )
      ticket = PlayedTicket( numbers )
      tickets.append( ticket )

    ticket_map[group] = tickets

  return ticket_map


def load_tickets_txt( filename, ticket_class = PlayedTicket ):
  '''Loads tickets from a text file.
  @param filename: The filename to load the tickets from.
  @param ticket_class: (optional) The class name for the type of tickets you want returned.
  @return: A map of # of tickets to an array of Tickets.'''

  global g_config

  # Read the file into an array of lines.
  fd = open( filename, 'r' )
  lines = fd.readlines()
  fd.close()

  # Create the hand picked list of tickets.
  ticket_list = parse_number_lines( lines, ticket_class )
  number_of_tickets = len( ticket_list )

  if ticket_class != QuickPick:
    # Add the appropriate number of quick picks.
    num_quick_picks = number_of_tickets * g_config['how_many_quick_pick_lines']
    ticket_list.extend( quick_picks( num_quick_picks ) )

  tickets = {number_of_tickets : ticket_list}

  return tickets


def load_winning_numbers( lines ):
  '''Loads the winning numbers from a CSV file and returns an array of WinningNumbers.
  @param lines: The lines of the CSV containing the winning numbers.
  @return: An array of WinningNumbers objects.'''

  global g_config

  numbers = []
  winning_tickets = []

  # Parse the string lines into arrays of numbers.
  for line in lines:
    numbers.append( parse_number_line( line ) )

  how_many_numbers = g_config['how_many_numbers']
  how_many_bonus = g_config['how_many_bonus']

  # Create an array of WinningTickets.
  for line in numbers:
    if len( line ) != (how_many_numbers + how_many_bonus):
      raise Exception( "Invalid winning numbers CSV file!  There should be %d numbers, but we found %d!" % (how_many_numbers + how_many_bonus, len( line ) ) )
    else:
      nums = line[0:how_many_numbers]
      bonus = line[-how_many_bonus:]
      ticket = WinningNumbers( nums, bonus )
      winning_tickets.append( ticket )

  return winning_tickets


def parse_number_lines( lines, ticket_class = PlayedTicket ):
  '''Parses an array of strings (comma delimited number lines).
  @param lines: An array of strings (comma delimited number lines).
  @param ticket_class: (optional) The class name for the type of tickets you want returned.
  @return: An array of tickets of the type specified by ticket_class.'''

  tickets = []

  for line in lines:
    numbers = parse_number_line( line )
    tickets.append( ticket_class( numbers ) )

  return tickets


def parse_number_line( line ):
  '''Parses a string (comma delimited number line).
  @param line: A string (comma delimited number line).
  @return: An array of sorted numbers.'''

  nums = line.split( ',' )
  numbers = []

  for num in nums:
    numbers.append( int( num.strip() ) )

  return sorted( numbers )


def quick_pick():
  '''Returns a QuickPick ticket.
  @return: A QuickPick ticket.'''

  global g_config, g_quick_pick_file
  random.seed()
  numbers = []

  while len( numbers ) < g_config['how_many_numbers']:
    num = random.randrange( g_config['min_number'], g_config['max_number'], 1 )  # From 1 to 49, step by 1.

    if not num in numbers:
      numbers.append( num )

  # If we're using a quick pick file, this function should never be called, so print this to let us know.
  if g_config['verbose'] and g_quick_pick_file:
    print( "Warning: You specified a quick pick file, but quick_pick() was called and returned: %s" % str(numbers) )

  return QuickPick( numbers )


def quick_picks( number_of_tickets, quick_pick_list=None ):
  '''Returns a list of QuickPick tickets.
  @param number_of_tickets: The number of QuickPick tickets to generate.
  @param quick_pick_list: (optional) Get as many quick picks from this list instead of generating new ones.
  @return: A list of QuickPick tickets.'''

  tickets = []

  if quick_pick_list:
    if len( quick_pick_list ) >= number_of_tickets:
      tickets.extend( quick_pick_list[0:number_of_tickets] )
    else:
      tickets.extend( quick_pick_list )

      for i in range( number_of_tickets - len( quick_pick_list ) ):
        tickets.append( quick_pick() )
  else:
    for i in range( number_of_tickets ):
      tickets.append( quick_pick() )

  return tickets


def single_play( played_tickets, winning_numbers ):
  '''Compares tickets to winning numbers and calculates what each ticket won.
  The 'amount_won' member will be set for any tickets that won.
  @param played_tickets: An array of PlayedTickets.
  @param winning_numbers: A WinningNumbers object.
  @return: A tuple of ($$ won, # free tickets won).'''

  global g_total_money_won, g_total_tickets_won, g_config, g_how_many_tickets_played
  total_money = 0
  total_tickets = 0
  num_tickets = len( played_tickets )

  # Compare each ticket against the winning numbers.
  for i in range( 0, num_tickets - 1 ):
    ticket = played_tickets[i]
    g_how_many_tickets_played = g_how_many_tickets_played + 1

    if g_config['verbose']:
      print( "[%s] = %s" % (played_tickets[i].name(), str(played_tickets[i])) )

    (money_won, tickets_won) = ticket.compare_with( winning_numbers )
    total_money = total_money + money_won
    total_tickets = total_tickets + tickets_won

  # Keep track of the totals won over all.
  g_total_money_won = g_total_money_won + total_money
  g_total_tickets_won = g_total_tickets_won + total_tickets

  return (total_money, total_tickets)


def get_tickets( played_ticket_map, how_many_tickets, keys ):
  '''Returns an array of tickets of the specified size, with as many hand_picked tickets as possible.
  @param played_ticket_map: A map of # of tickets to array of PlayedTickets to choose from.
  @param how_many_tickets: The number of tickets to be returned.
  @param keys: The sorted list of keys in played_ticket_map.
  @return: An array of tickets of the specified size, with as many hand_picked tickets as possible.'''

  global g_ticket_quick_picks
  tickets = []

  # If any of the ticket pools have the exact number of tickets we need, use it; otherwise add quick picks
  # to a ticket pool that's smaller than we need until we have the right number of tickets.
  if how_many_tickets in keys:
    tickets = copy.deepcopy(played_ticket_map[how_many_tickets] )
  else:
    # Find next ticket pool lower than how_many_tickets and add quick picks to fill up the rest.
    last_key_index = -1

    for i in keys:
      if i > how_many_tickets:
        break

      last_key_index = i

    if last_key_index == -1:
      # Looks like we're using all quick picks.
      print( "*** get_tickets() is adding all %d quick picks" % how_many_tickets )           # DEBUG
      tickets = quick_picks( how_many_tickets, g_ticket_quick_picks )
    else:
      if (how_many_tickets - last_key_index) > 50:
        print( "*** get_tickets() is adding %d quick picks" % (how_many_tickets - last_key_index) )  # DEBUG
      tickets = copy.deepcopy( played_ticket_map[last_key_index] )
      tickets.extend( quick_picks( how_many_tickets - last_key_index, g_ticket_quick_picks ) )

  return tickets


def multiple_plays( played_ticket_map, quick_pick_list_const, winning_numbers, number_of_tickets ):
  '''Compares tickets to an array of winning numbers and calculates what each ticket won over x number of games played.
  The 'amount_won' member will be set for any tickets that won.
  @param played_ticket_map: A map of # of tickets to array of PlayedTickets to choose from.
  @param quick_pick_list_const: A list of QuickPick tickets to choose from.
  @param winning_numbers: An array of WinningNumbers objects.
  @param number_of_tickets: The usual number of tickets bought (assuming no extra or free tickets).
  @return: A tuple of: (extra_tickets, extra_quick_picks, money_left_over)'''

  global g_ticket_quick_picks, g_config

  extra_tickets = 0
  extra_quick_picks = 0
  money_left_over = 0

  amount_won = 0
  tickets_won = 0
  game_num = 0
  keys = sorted( played_ticket_map.keys() )

  # For each winning ticket, check if any of our tickets won.
  for winning_ticket in winning_numbers:
    total_tickets_won = 0
    total_amount_won = 0
    game_num += 1

    if g_config['verbose']:
      print( "Winning numbers are: %s" % winning_ticket )

    # Check the hand picked tickets.
    how_many_tickets = number_of_tickets + extra_tickets
    tickets = get_tickets( played_ticket_map, how_many_tickets, keys )

    # Play the numbers we picked.
    (amount_won, tickets_won) = single_play( tickets, winning_ticket )
    for ticket in tickets:
      del ticket
    del tickets
    total_amount_won = total_amount_won + amount_won
    total_tickets_won = total_tickets_won + tickets_won

    # Check the quick picks.
    how_many_quick_picks = (g_config['how_many_quick_pick_lines'] * number_of_tickets) + extra_quick_picks

    # Make a copy of quick_pick_list_const.
    quick_pick_list = quick_pick_list_const[0:len(quick_pick_list_const)]

    # If the quick_pick pool isn't big enough, increase the pool size.
    if len( quick_pick_list ) < how_many_quick_picks:
      quick_pick_list.extend( quick_picks( how_many_quick_picks - len(quick_pick_list), g_ticket_quick_picks ) )

    # Now play the quick picks.
    (amount_won, tickets_won) = single_play( quick_pick_list[0:how_many_quick_picks], winning_ticket )
    total_amount_won = total_amount_won + amount_won
    total_tickets_won = total_tickets_won + tickets_won

    # Now change the number of quick picks and extra money to reflect what we just won.
    if g_config['verbose']:
      print( "[Game %d]: We won: $%d, and %d Free Tickets.\n\n" % (game_num, total_amount_won, total_tickets_won) )

    extra_tickets = int( (total_amount_won + money_left_over) / g_config['cost_per_ticket'] )
    money_left_over = total_amount_won + money_left_over - (extra_tickets * g_config['cost_per_ticket'])
    extra_quick_picks = total_tickets_won
  return (extra_tickets, extra_quick_picks, money_left_over)


def main():
  '''The start of the program.'''

  global g_ticket_quick_picks, g_quick_pick_file, g_config, g_total_money_won, g_total_tickets_won, g_prizes_won, \
    g_how_many_tickets_played, g_how_many_tickets_won

  # Create the arg parser.
  usage = """\
usage: %prog -c <config_file> -t <tickets_file> -w <winning_numbers_file> [-q <quick_pick_file>] [-o <quick_pick_output_file>] [-T] [-v]
   or: %prog -c <config_file> -o <quick_pick_output_file> [-v]
  -c, --config       The main config file.
  -t, --tickets      The tickets config file.
  -o, --output       Will dump some quick pick numbers into this file.
  -w, --winning-numbers  The winning numbers csv file.
  -d, --debug        Debug mode.
  -T, --text         Read tickets_file as a text file instead of a config file.
  -v, --verbose      Enable verbose mode."""
  parser = OptionParser( usage=usage )
  parser.add_option( '-c', '--config', dest='config_file' )
  parser.add_option( '-t', '--tickets', dest='tickets_file' )
  parser.add_option( '-o', '--output', dest='output_file' )
  parser.add_option( '-q', '--quick-pick', dest='quick_pick_file' )
  parser.add_option( '-w', '--winning-numbers', dest='winning_numbers' )
  parser.add_option( '-d', '--debug', action='store_true', dest='debug_mode' )
  parser.add_option( '-T', '--text', action='store_true', dest='text_mode' )
  parser.add_option( '-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', dest='verbose' )
  (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

  if len( args ):
    parser.error( "The following arguments are unrecognized: %s" % str( args ) )

  if (not options.config_file):
    parser.error( "--config is a required parameter!" )

  # Load the main config file.
  load_config( options.config_file )
  ticket_map = None
  g_config['debug_mode'] = False
  g_config['verbose'] = False

  if options.debug_mode:
    g_config['debug_mode'] = True

  if options.verbose:
    g_config['verbose'] = True

  if g_config['verbose']:
    # Print out current configuration.
    print( "min_number = %s" % g_config['min_number'] )
    print( "max_number = %s" % g_config['max_number'] )
    print( "how_many_numbers = %s" % g_config['how_many_numbers'] )
    print( "how_many_bonus = %s" % g_config['how_many_bonus'] )
    print( "how_many_hand_picked_lines = %s" % g_config['how_many_hand_picked_lines'] )
    print( "how_many_quick_pick_lines = %s" % g_config['how_many_quick_pick_lines'] )
    print( "cost_per_ticket = %s" % g_config['cost_per_ticket'] )
    print( "quick_pick_pool_size = %s" % g_config['quick_pick_pool_size'] )
    print( "how_many_tickets_bought = %s" % g_config['how_many_tickets_bought'] )
    print( "verbose mode = %s\n" % str(g_config['verbose']) )


  # Load the quick pick pool from a file or generate the numbers.
  quick_pick_pool = []
  if options.quick_pick_file:
    g_quick_pick_file = options.quick_pick_file
    quick_pick_map = load_tickets_txt( options.quick_pick_file, QuickPick )
    for key, val in quick_pick_map.items():
      quick_pick_pool = val
  else:
    quick_pick_pool = quick_picks( g_config['quick_pick_pool_size'] )


  if (options.output_file):   # Just output some quick picks.
    if ((options.tickets_file) or (options.winning_numbers) or (options.text_mode)):
      parser.error( "--output cannot be used with --tickets or --winning-numbers or --text!" )

    else:
      # Just output some quick picks to a file.
      fd = open( options.output_file, 'w' )
      for quick_pick in quick_pick_pool:
        fd.write( str( quick_pick ) + '\n' )
      fd.close()
  else:   # Play the games.
    # Move half the quick pick pool to g_ticket_quick_picks for use with normal tickets.
    for i in range( (len(quick_pick_pool) / 2) ):
      g_ticket_quick_picks.append( quick_pick_pool.pop(0) )

    if (not options.tickets_file) or (not options.winning_numbers):
      parser.error( "Incorrect number of arguments!" )
    else:
      # Load the tickets & winning numbers.
      if options.text_mode:
        ticket_map = load_tickets_txt( options.tickets_file )
      else:
        ticket_map = load_tickets_conf( options.tickets_file )

      # Read the file into an array of lines.
      fd = open( options.winning_numbers, 'r' )
      lines = []
      extra_tickets   = 0
      extra_quick_picks = 0
      money_left_over   = 0

      while True:
        for i in range( 1000 ):
          line = fd.readline()
          if not line:
            break
          lines.append( line )
        if not lines:
          break

        winning_numbers = load_winning_numbers( lines )

        # Start the simulation.
        (extra_tickets, extra_quick_picks, money_left_over) = multiple_plays( ticket_map, quick_pick_pool, winning_numbers, g_config['how_many_tickets_bought'] )
        del lines
        lines = []

      print( "After %d games, we won a total of $%d and %d Free Tickets ($%d)." % (len( winning_numbers ), g_total_money_won, g_total_tickets_won, (g_total_tickets_won * 5 + g_total_money_won)) )
      print( "We played %d ticket lines and %d lines won." % (g_how_many_tickets_played, g_how_many_tickets_won) )
      fd.close()

      # Now display the results of all the games.
      for (key, value) in sorted( g_prizes.items() ):
        if g_prizes_won.has_key( value ):
          print( "  '%s' won, %d times." % (value, g_prizes_won[value]) )


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Here's a sample config file you can use (with the --config option) to run the program (I'll call this **lotto.conf**):

```
# Stores config info for the lotto simulation program.

[GameType]
min_number = 1
max_number = 49
how_many_numbers = 7
how_many_bonus = 1
how_many_hand_picked_lines = 1
how_many_quick_pick_lines = 2
cost_per_ticket = 5
quick_pick_pool_size = 10000
how_many_tickets_bought = 20

[Prizes]
# prizes = {(numbers matched, bonus matched) : $$ won, ...}
prizes = {(3, 0) : '3', (3, 1) : '3+1', (4, 0) : '4', (5, 0) : '5', (6, 0) : '6', (6, 1) : '6+1', (7, 0) : '7'}

# -1 means Free Ticket.
prize_amounts = {'3' : -1, '3+1' : 20, '4' : 20, '5' : 134, '6' : 6145, '6+1' : 325676, '7' : 15000000}
```

and a sample tickets file you can use (with the --tickets option), I'll call this **tickets.conf**:

```
[AllTicketGroups]
all_groups = 7, 13

[7]
1 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
2 = 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
3 = 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21
4 = 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
5 = 29, 30 ,31, 32, 33, 34, 35
6 = 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42
7 = 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49

[13]
1 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
2 = 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
3 = 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21
4 = 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
5 = 29, 30 ,31, 32, 33, 34, 35
6 = 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42
7 = 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49
8 = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13
9 = 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14
10 = 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27
11 = 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28
12 = 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41
13 = 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42
```

To generate a **winning_numbers.csv** file (to be used with the --winning-numbers option) edit the lotto.conf file and simply change the how_many_hand_picked_lines to equal 8 instead of 7 and set quick_pick_pool_size to the number of winning number lines you want to generate, then run:

> ./lotto.py --config lotto.conf --output winning_numbers.csv

Then to run the simulation, undo your changes to lotto.conf and run:
**./lotto.py -c lotto.conf -t tickets.conf -w winning_numbers.csv**

But to make tests repeatable, I also added the ability to include a pre-generated set of Quick Picks in a file (which you can use on the command above with the -q option).

Comment: Did not know you could leak in python (but then I am not that good at python). Would be interested in the bug you did fix.

Comment: @Martin, you can leak in any garbage collected language. GC languages just free objects which it is no longer possible to access. You can keep those objects around by having a reference to them such as in a list or dictionary.

Comment: @Chris, how do you know you have a memory leak?

Comment: @Winston Ewert: If they are in a list or a dictionary then they are not technically leaked (I would assume that if you got rid of the container the contained objects would eventually also be GC). Yes I understand that a loop of object with no external objects can potentially be leaked by a GC but I would hope that most modern GC could handle this situation.

Comment: @Martin, the point is that objects can be kept in memory longer then you intended because you accidentally kept them referenced when you didn't mean to. These are called memory leaks even though in some sense, the memory isn't lost because its still accessible.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: OK That makes sense.

Comment: You can't leak in the true sense in a managed language, but the result is of course the same; memory usage grows and the program cannot account for that as it stands.

Comment: @Ed not completely true, unsafe blocks in C# can leak memory or many other things I'm sure, but I think in an interpreted language the script cannot leak memory- only the interpreter may, which python's probably does not. So I would agree I don't believe there could be a memory leak in python outside of a bug in the interpreter.

Comment: @Martin: Originally I loaded the entire Winning-numbers.csv file into memory; but when I tried it with a 300,000 line file, it filled up all my RAM and Page File, so I changed it to only load 1000 lines at a time.  The thing I forgot to do was to set 'lines = []' after each iteration.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: I know I have a memory leak because when I watch the memory in the System Monitor while I'm running against a large dataset (300,000 winning number lines), my memory keeps going up.  I had to increase my Virtual Machine's memory to 1.5GB to be able to run on a dataset that large.

Comment: For tracing memory leaks have a look at: http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/

Comment: Use python conventions when writing python code. `g_*` `TicketNumbers( object ):` depict global by using SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE and avoid using spaces like that inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random, ConfigParser, ast, copy
from optparse import OptionParser

# Global variables.
g_config = {}               # Stores GameType config options.
g_prizes = {}               # Stores prizes from config file.
g_prize_amounts = {}        # Stores prize amounts from config file.
g_ticket_quick_picks = []   # Store an array of QuickPicks to use for tickets.
g_total_money_won = 0
g_total_tickets_won = 0
g_prizes_won = {}           # Format: {'3':3, '3+1':2, '4':2 ...}
g_quick_pick_file = ''
g_how_many_tickets_played = 0
g_how_many_tickets_won = 0
```

In Python, it is recommended not have global variables. I usually only put constants at the global level, and according to python style guide they should be written WITH_ALL_CAPS. I'd move all of this data into some sort of object.

```
class TicketNumbers( object ):
    '''Represents the numbers of a ticket (or the 7 winning numbers).
    @var numbers: A sorted array of 7 unique numbers from 1-49.'''
```

Considering the fact that you later sort the number, why do specify that it should be sorted on input?

```
    def __init__( self, numbers ):
        '''Constructor.
        @param numbers: The numbers for this ticket.'''

        self.numbers = numbers
```

You assign to numbers here, but _set_numbers also assigns to it. This one is pointless.

```
        self._set_numbers( numbers )

    def name( self ):
        '''Return the name of this class type.'''
        return "TicketNumbers"
```

What's the point of this? If you want the name of the class use `obj.__class__.__name__`

```
    def __str__( self ):
        '''Returns a string of the number list.'''
        str_nums = []
        for i in range( len( self.numbers ) ):
```

There is almost never a need to use the range( len( container pattern. Just iterate over the numbers directly.

```
            str_nums.append( str( self.numbers[i] ) )
```

There are a number of ways of writing this loop more simply:

```
str_nums = [str(number) for number in self.numbers]
str_nums = map(str, self.numbers)

        return ', '.join( str_nums )
```

Actually, the entire function can be written as:

```
return ', '.join(str(number) for number in self.numbers)


    def _set_numbers( self, numbers ):
        '''Sets the numbers member variable and validates the numbers.
        @param numbers: The numbers to assign.'''

        global g_config
        self.numbers = sorted( numbers )

        if len( self.numbers ) != int(g_config['how_many_numbers']):
            raise Exception( "You must have %d numbers, but found %d numbers: %s" % (g_config['how_many_numbers'], len( self.numbers ), str(self.numbers)) )
```

If you are validating user input, I suggest create a custom exception class. You should then catch this custom class and print just the error message instead of having python's default. Your error message should also give a better indication of where the numbers are from.

```
        tmp = []
```

tmp is a terrible variable name, because all local variables are temporary.

```
        for num in self.numbers:
            # Check if numbers are in range.
            if ( num < int(g_config['min_number']) ) or ( num > int(g_config['max_number']) ):
```

I recommend pulling configuration data into the correct types inside your configuration logic not in the rest of your code.

```
                raise Exception( "The numbers must be between %d & %d!" % (int(g_config['min_number']), int(g_config['max_number'])) )
            # Check for duplicate numbers.
            if num in tmp:
                raise Exception( "You cannot have duplicate numbers!  %d in %s" % (num, str( self.numbers )) )
            tmp.append( num )
```

I suggest splitting these check out into three seperate bits:

```
if min(self.numbers) < config.min_number:
     raise UserError("Too low!")
if max(self.numbers) > config.max_number:
     raise UserError("Too high!")
if len(set(self.numbers)) != len(self.numbers):
     raise UserError("duplicates!")


class PlayedTicket( TicketNumbers ):
    '''Represents a ticket that was played.
    @var amount_won: How much $$ this ticket won.'''
```

A ticket isn't a special kind of TicketNumbers. The names suggest that a ticket should contain numbers.

```
    def __init__( self, numbers ):
        '''Constructor.
        @param numbers: The numbers for this ticket.'''

        super( PlayedTicket, self ).__init__( numbers )
        self.amount_won = {}    # Map of Game Index to $$ won each play.
        self.tickets_won = {}   # Map of Game Index to Free Tickets won each play.

    def name( self ):
        '''Return the name of this class type.'''
        return "PlayedTicket"

    def compare_with( self, winning_numbers, game_index=None ):
        '''Compares this ticket with the specified winning numbers and sets the amount_won & tickets_won members accordingly.
        @param winning_numbers: The winning numbers to compare against.
        @param game_index: (optional) The game index for this game.  Defaults to 1 + the number of games recorded.
        @return: A tuple of ($$ won, # free tickets won).'''
```

The name compare_with doesn't suggest that this method will modify the object's state. I suggest picking a number that will.

```
        global g_config, g_prizes, g_prize_amounts, g_prizes_won, g_how_many_tickets_won
        nums_correct = 0
        bonus_correct = 0
        amount_won = 0
        tickets_won = 0

        if game_index == None:
            game_index = len( self.amount_won )

        # Check each individual number of the ticket against the winning numbers.
        for num in self.numbers:
            if num in winning_numbers.numbers:
                nums_correct = nums_correct + 1
            elif num in winning_numbers.bonus_numbers:
                bonus_correct = bonus_correct + 1
```

The numbers really function as sets not lists. That is, you can't have duplicates and the order doesn't matter. I suggest you change from using lists to using sets. Then you can just find the intersection of the ticket numbers and the winning number rather then needing a counting loop.

```
        # Now see if we won anything.
        for (key, value) in g_prizes.items():
            main_nums = key[0]
            bonus_nums = key[1]
```

Use
      main_nums, bonus_nums = key

```
            if (main_nums == nums_correct) and ((bonus_nums == bonus_correct) or (bonus_nums == 0)):
```

A dictionary is designed to enable fast lookup. You shouldn't be iterating over it. You should use:

```
 value = g_prizes[(nums_correct, bonus_correct)]
```

To directly fetch the value for the prize you've won.

```
                if not g_prizes_won.has_key( value ):
                    g_prizes_won[value] = 0
```

Make g_prizes_won a `collections.defaultdict(int)` object. Then it will automatically act as though all unset values are zero and this piece of code will be unnecessary.

```
                g_how_many_tickets_won = g_how_many_tickets_won + 1
                g_prizes_won[value] = g_prizes_won[value] + 1  # Increment map of how many times each prize won.
```

If you break those global variables into an object as I suggest, then a bunch of this should live in a method on that object.

```
                # We won.   Now figure out what we won.
                if g_prize_amounts[value] > amount_won:
                    amount_won = g_prize_amounts[value]
                    tickets_won = 0
                elif g_prize_amounts[value] == -1:
                    amount_won = 0
                    tickets_won = 1
```

You are picking the best prize of all the ones you qualify for. However, as mentioned before you should be able to directly fetch exactly the prize you are supposed to get without looping. So there is no need to get the best prize of the ones you've considered.

```
        if amount_won or tickets_won:
            if g_config['verbose']:
                print( "Ticket %s won: $%d & %d Free tickets." % (str(self.numbers), amount_won, tickets_won) )

        # Set and return the amount won.
        self.amount_won[game_index] = amount_won
        self.tickets_won[game_index] = tickets_won
        return (amount_won, tickets_won)


class QuickPick( PlayedTicket ):
    '''Represents a Quick Pick ticket.'''

    def __init__( self, numbers ):
        '''Constructor.
        @param numbers: The numbers for this ticket.'''

        super( QuickPick, self ).__init__( numbers )
        self.amount_won = {}    # Map of Game Index to $$ won each play.
        self.tickets_won = {}   # Map of Game Index to Free Tickets won each play.
```

The subclass already creates these, why are you creating them again

```
    def name( self ):
        '''Return the name of this class type.'''
        return "QuickPick"
```

This class didn't do anything.

```
class WinningNumbers( TicketNumbers ):
    '''Represents the winning numbers + bonus number.
    @var bonus_numbers: The bonus numbers.'''

    def __init__( self, numbers, bonus_numbers=None ):
        '''Constructor.
        @param numbers: The winning numbers.
        @param bonus_numbers: (optional) The bonus number(s).  Defaults to empty list.'''

        global g_config
        bonus_numbers = bonus_numbers or []
        super( WinningNumbers, self ).__init__( numbers )
        self.bonus_numbers = []
        if bonus_numbers:
            self.bonus_numbers = sorted( bonus_numbers )
```

There is no need to check if bonus_numbers is empty, just let it assign the empty sorted list.

```
        tmp = []

        if len( bonus_numbers ) != int(g_config['how_many_bonus']):
            raise Exception( "You must have %d bonus numbers!" % int(g_config['how_many_bonus']) )

        for num in bonus_numbers:
            if (num in tmp) or (num in self.numbers):
                raise Exception( "You cannot have duplicate numbers!" )
            tmp.append( num )

    def __str__( self ):
        '''Converts this class into a string.'''
        ret = super( WinningNumbers, self ).__str__()

        str_bnums = []

        if len( self.bonus_numbers ):
            for i in range( len( self.bonus_numbers ) ):
                str_bnums.append( str( self.bonus_numbers[i] ) )

            ret = ret + ' + ' + ', '.join( str_bnums )

        return ret


    def name( self ):
        '''Return the name of this class type.'''
        return "WinningNumbers"


def load_config( filename ):
    '''Reads the config file to load program defaults.
    @param filename: The filename of the config file.
    @return: A ConfigParser object containing the parsed config file.'''

    # Read the config file into the parser.
    global g_config, g_prizes, g_prize_amounts
    conf = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
    conf.read( filename )

    if (not conf.has_section( 'GameType' )) or (not conf.has_section( 'Prizes' )):
```

Too many parantehsis, use:

```
    if not conf.has_section( 'GameType' ) or not conf.has_section( 'Prizes' ):

        raise Exception( "Invalid config file!  [GameType] and/or [Prizes] sections are missing!" )

    options = ['min_number', 'max_number', 'how_many_numbers', 'how_many_bonus', 'how_many_hand_picked_lines', 'how_many_quick_pick_lines', 'cost_per_ticket', 'quick_pick_pool_size', 'how_many_tickets_bought']

    for option in options:
        if not conf.has_option( 'GameType', option ):
            raise Exception( "Invalid config file!  '%s' option is missing!" % option )

        g_config[option] = int( conf.get( 'GameType', option ) )

    # Prizes section contains maps.
    g_prizes = ast.literal_eval( conf.get( 'Prizes', 'prizes' ) )
    g_prize_amounts = ast.literal_eval( conf.get( 'Prizes', 'prize_amounts' ) )
```

(Rest of code skipped.)

Comment: Wow, thanks Winston!  I'll take a closer look at your suggestions when I get home and try them out.  For some of your questions like the code comments...  They're probably a little out of date, since the code changed a lot since my original version.
Ex. in the __init__() function I set self.numbers = numbers then later I added the _set_numbers() function.

Comment: I made some of the changes you suggested, and after looking into the compare_with() function (because of your "The name compare_with doesn't suggest that this method will modify the object's state." comment) I found my memory leak.  I was storing a huge amount of data in the self.amount_won and self.tickets_won member variables, and then never using them, so I just removed them.  Now my program's memory and speed are constant.  Thanks!